# Как использовать useCollectionData, когда данные придут

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Получаю данные о пользователях с firebase через useCollectionData(), но пытаясь их перебрать через map(), получаю ошибку - нельзя применить map() к undefined. Понимаю, что это асинхронный запрос, но не могу понять, как реализовать использование данных только тогда, когда они придут
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

используйте опциональную цепочку

```
const renderItems = (arr) => {
  const items = arr?.map((item, i) => {
...
```

а лучше еще и мемоизируйте их

```
const memoizedItems = useMemo(() => renderItems(test), [test]);
```